# Implicit access to page (product, collection, page, etc...) object in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is there a way in a Shopify theme to get access to the current page object (product, collection, page, article, etc….) in `Liquid` without being explicit about the page type?

I’d like to avoid doing {{ page. handle }} or {{ product.handle }}, instead I want to do {{ object.handle }} and I want it to work globally regardless of the page type.

At the moment I’m able to do this:

```
{% liquid
  case request.page_type
    when 'page'
      assign obj = page
    when 'product'
      assign obj = product
  endcase
%}

Page handle: {{ obj.handle }}
```

Is there a way to achieve this without the case statement?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has a global object called `handle`([Ref](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/handle)), it'll provide access to the current page handle, however it's only available for the following page types:

- blogs
- articles
- collections
- pages
- products